# Android - best practice approach for refreshing page data at a certain interval?

Tags: android

I have a page that goes out to the database and gets the latest data.  The problem is that multiple users can access that data. So if someone adds to the data, the current screen does not update, and the user is confused.

What is the best way to keep refreshing the data on the page for the user? Should I send a call to the server every 30 seconds or so to get the latest? If that is the only approach, do I have to make a new thread for that? How is that best accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of C2DM? I think it's what you're looking for, if you're developing for some newer platform

Comment: @MichałK actually not familiar with it.  Will have to look it up :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `WebView`, you can try something like this,

```
// Wait 60 seconds before reloading
private static final int WAIT_TIME = 60000;

mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);
mWebView.loadUrl(/* ENTER URL HERE */);

new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
         mWebView.reload();
    }
}, WAIT_TIME, WAIT_TIME);
```

Comment: I have not really been using webview.  I just have basic Activities.

Comment: OK, well then you would just need to replace the `mWebView.reload()` with code that will refresh the page appropriately. I'm not sure how you are implementing your code, but the use of a `Timer` here (as I described) should give you a good idea on how to schedule refresh tasks.