# Pass data with event between Activities in Tabs - Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabactivity

I have a TabActivity with 4 Tabs (Activities) in it.
Now I want to pass data between these 4 Tabs. I know how to pass it to the parent (TabActivity), but how do I pass it to one of the running Tabs' Activities? With putExtra I can pass it some data, but how do I know in the other Activity that it got data (something like an Event/Callback/whatever)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if the data is in the intent with getExtra. I would solve this with public static variables. The simply get the reference to the Object from onResume in your activity. Remember to check that it's null

Comment: I was hoping for a onContextChange or something like that, but I guess onResume will do the trick for now. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

Each Activitys in Tab has its context. You can put extra/ get Extra as normal.

Another ways are:

Make public static variable.
Preference.

Store it in SQLite.

Comment: Yes I know this solution, as I mentioned in my question. But I want to inform the second Activity that it got something right now, an event or callback or smthn. Or do I really have to make a timer and check via getExtra if it's null or not?

Comment: your question is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665106/android-best-practice-approach-for-refreshing-page-data-at-a-certain-interval/10665878#10665878   But it 's still no solution.